# Can we perform comparison operations on two different Streams in Java8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've two streams of Integer array and I wanted to check whether all the elements of the first stream are smaller than the second one. Like Python tuple, we can compare elements of two different tuples with the same index.

```
if (ry, rm, rd) <= (ey, em, ed):
print(0)
```

here, for example, we can compare all elements with a single operator. I want to achieve the same in java.

can we do similar with java streams?

```
boolean check(int a1[],int a2[])
{
    boolean flag= true;
    IntStream s1 = Arrays.stream(a1);
    IntStream s2 = Arrays.stream(a2);
    Iterator<Integer> it1 = s1.iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> it2 = s2.iterator();
    while(it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext())
    {
        if(it1.next() > it2.next())
            flag = false;
    }
    return flag ;
}
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `IntStream` and `allMatch` if both the arrays `a1` and `a2` are of same length. Still you can give the max length of smaller size array were you will get the same expected result

```
int[] a2 = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] a1 = { 0, 1, 2 };

int[] a3 = {0,1};

boolean result = IntStream.range(0, a1.length).allMatch(i -> a1[i] < a2[i]);

// using less than or equal to
boolean result1 = IntStream.range(0, a3.length).allMatch(i -> a3[i] <= a1[i]);

System.out.println(result);    //true

System.out.println(result1);    //true
```

In the same way you can also use `anyMatch` in reverse condition so that you don't need to traverse whole stream after failure case

```
boolean result2 = IntStream.range(0, a1.length).anyMatch(i->a1[i]>a2[i]);
```

Comment: This would work only if both arrays are of the same size.

Comment: one needs to make sure to iterate using the smaller size array in the input which is what the existing code in question would work like.

Comment: But Efficient approach Using IntStream.

Comment: He can give the range of smaller size array which achieves the result what he want @NicholasK

Comment: Can we directly compare or perform operations on two streams ??

Comment: No you cannot, because this is java not python, for sure you need to traverse both the stream either way @AashishPawar

Answer (score 1):

You may use Guava Streams for zipping two streams and compare them in a Bi-Function. Please see [the link for details](https://www.baeldung.com/java-collections-zip).

```java
Stream<Integer> aStream = Stream.of(0, 2, 3);
        Stream<Integer> bStream = Stream.of(1, 1, 3);

        System.out.println(Streams
                                .zip(aStream, bStream, (i, j) -> i >= j)
                                .allMatch(b -> b)
                        );
```